# DragGesture blocks touching a Slider in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, ios14

Let's take a look at this code:

```
@State private var progress: TimeInterval = 0
@State private var sliderMoving: Bool = false

Slider(value: $progress, in: 0 ... Double(100), onEditingChanged: { didChange in
    seekToProgress(p: progress)
}).simultaneousGesture(
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
        .onChanged { gesture in
            print("gesture onChanged")
            sliderMoving = true
        }
        .onEnded { gesture in
            print("gesture onEnded")
            sliderMoving = false
        }
)
```

I want to track touch down and end events on the slider, but this blocks the actual Slider from being touched. In another words, DragGesture seems to consuming touches despite using simultaneousGesture. I've also tried adding GestureMask.all, but it didn't work either. How can I fix this? I need to keep track of touch down/up, because this slider is used to seek an audio track, but also audio tracks updates the slider. However it shoudn't do it, when user is touching the slider (and sliderMoving flag should handle this).

Similar approach works with button tapping, but not with slider moving.

edit:

I'm posting the final answer, thanks to @Marco Boerner for a big help:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    Slider(value: $progress, in: 0 ... Double(100), onEditingChanged: { didChange in
        
        print("onEditingChanged") //not used
        
    })
    .simultaneousGesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onChanged { gesture in
                sliderMoving = true
                updateProgress(x: gesture.location.x, width: geometry.size.width)
            }
            .onEnded { gesture in
                sliderMoving = false
                updateProgress(x: gesture.location.x, width: geometry.size.width)
                seekToProgress(p: progress)
            }
        )
}

private func updateProgress(x: CGFloat, width: CGFloat) {
    let knobWidth: CGFloat = 30
    if x < knobWidth / 2 {
        progress = TimeInterval(0)
    } else if x >= width - knobWidth / 2 {
        progress = TimeInterval(100)
    } else {
        let x2 = x - knobWidth / 2
        let width2 = width - knobWidth
        progress = TimeInterval(x2 / (width2 / 100))
    } 
}
```

The only downside is we have assume that knob has a fixed value, but because I'm setting slider height to 30 anyway, it works flawlessly in my case.

Comment: We had a similar issue and tried all sorts of approaches. I think you cannot have two of the same gestures run at the same time. And assuming Slider has its own DragGesture they seem to be interfering. Using a TapGesture instead of DragGesture works for the touch up but it doesn't register the touch downs. Have you tried moving the `sliderMoving = true` inside of the `didChange` of the slider itself, and using `sliderMoving = false` with a TapGesture's .onEnded?

Comment: This approach doesn't work - onTapGesture is called only when tapped in place and even worse didChange is always called after it. So it just stops slider from being updated when track is playing.

Comment: Okay I see, I think I was thinking wrong about that. How do you update the Slider programmatically when the audio track is playing? My idea is to set up your DragGesture to also update the slider programmatically. Basically completely circumventing the sliders gesture recognizer.

Comment: Okay I tried it and it seems to be working in my case and understanding. Try it out if this is the solution you were looking for. : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this solution works for you. As mentioned in my comment it's basically overwriting the gesture reader of the slider completely. To get the width I used a geometry reader. You could probably even use `.gesture` or even `.highPriorityGesture` instead of `simultaneousGesture` Also depending where you place the `GeometryReader` you might have to use the `.local coordinateSpace` of the gesture.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var progress: TimeInterval = 0
@State private var sliderMoving: Bool = false


var body: some View {
    
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        
        Slider(value: $progress, in: 0 ... Double(100), onEditingChanged: { didChange in
            
        }).simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    print("gesture onChanged")
                    sliderMoving = true
                    progress = TimeInterval(gesture.location.x / (geometry.size.width / 100))
                }
                .onEnded { gesture in
                    print("gesture onEnded")
                    sliderMoving = false
                    progress = TimeInterval(gesture.location.x / (geometry.size.width / 100))
                    }
            )
            
        }
    }
}
```

Update with addition to comment below. This optionally adjusts to the padding modifier and knob size. Depending how the slider is setup different adjustments might be needed to get the exact position. I'm not currently aware of a way to get the exact locations of individual parts of the slider. A custom slider might solve this problem.

```
struct ContentView6: View {
    
    @State private var progress: TimeInterval = 0
    @State private var sliderMoving: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            let padding: CGFloat = 0 //optional in case padding needs to be adjusted.
            let adjustment: CGFloat = padding + 15
            
            Slider(value: $progress, in: 0 ... Double(100), onEditingChanged: { didChange in
                
            })
            .padding(padding)
            .simultaneousGesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        sliderMoving = true
                        progress = TimeInterval( min(max((gesture.location.x - adjustment) / ((geometry.size.width - adjustment*2) / 100), 0), 100)  )
                        print(progress)
                    }
                    .onEnded { gesture in
                        sliderMoving = false
                    }
            )
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, this works! Adding GeometryReader caused a height problem (Slider got enormous height), but I fixed it by hardcoding frame height. This solution works pretty well, there's only small issue: progress calculated by dividing gesture.location.x by geometry.size.width isn't exactly what a knob points to, because it has small margins on the left and right (on the Slider).

Comment: Have you figured out how to solve the margin problem? One issue I see is that the actual "playhead" is not equal to the knobs center. I think since the knob is larger, on the left side of the slider, the knobs left edge is considered 0, in the center of the slider it's the knobs center, to the right it's the knobs right side. But then it can also have an effect if you use other modifiers like .padding on the slider because this will change its geometry. In this case you have to adjust the calculation. See my updates answer if that helps with the issue.

Comment: Thing is I'm not adding any padding to the slider. I probably didn't explain the issue very clearly: the knob has its size, so the "actual" area of changing progress value should be: knobWidth / 2 ... geometry.width - knobWidth / 2, everything below knobWidth / 2 should be considered as 0 and everything after geometry.width - knobWidth / 2 should be considered as 100. This is very small detail, but it's there and you can experience it while playing around with the slider.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out, I think. I posted a final solution :)

Comment: I think I briefly mentioned this too. I think the problem is, that the knob is not reaching over slider and in order for the knob to point to 0 or 100 the center of the knob is moving. Moving the knob from left to right also moves its center. I agree, the only way I can think of to change that is to adjust for half the knob width. In my example set padding to 0 and adjustment to half the slider side. I think Apple is planning something similar to ButtonStyle for sliders (SliderStyle) and hopefully this should allow you to change the style and therefor center of the slider.

Comment: My answer came the same time as yours. : ) Glad you figured it out! : )

Comment: I updated the second part of my answer as well in case you wanna have a look at it. But I think it's basically doing the same as you do, except using the min() and max() methods. : )

Comment: Seems like it, I wasn't aware of it :)

Comment: @MarcoBoerner You saved my life. The default Slider() is pretty janky. This override functionality allowed me to do what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Good work, @Marco Boerner & @Makalele. I too ran into the same issue today and with your help created a more universal solution. In my specific use case I had a Button with a custom DragGesture (to capture tap down and tap up events). When the button was held down it prevented a Slider view from updating as my custom DragGesture was taking priority.

A few comments on the code:

- I use a custom modifier "saveSize" which computes the size of the slider and stores it into a @State variable. This is important because we need to know the width of the slider to compute the new value. The width will change from screen to screen, or when orientation changes...
- I opted to use a .highPriorityGesture for our custom gesture extension to the slider. Doing so allows the Slider to behave as it normally would. Our custom code will only run if the Slider's DragGesture does not fire. In my case, it's when another DragGesture is currently active in the same view container.

First, here is the modifier to calculate the size of the slider:

```
struct SizeCalculator: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding var size: CGSize
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear // we just want the reader to get triggered, so let's use an empty color
                        .onAppear {
                            size = proxy.size
                        }
                }
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    func saveSize(in size: Binding<CGSize>) -> some View {
        modifier(SizeCalculator(size: size))
    }
}
```

Next, here is the Slider with the custom gesture extension which calls a function to compute the new slider value:

```
@State var sliderValue = 5000
@State var frequencySliderSize: CGSize = .zero

...

Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 100...20000, step: 100)
    .saveSize(in: $sliderSize) // -> SAVE THE REAL-TIME SIZE OF THE SLIDER
    .highPriorityGesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: geo.size.width * 0.01)
            .onChanged { gesture in
                sliderValue = calculateNewValue(
                    x: gesture.location.x,
                    width: sliderSize.width, // -> USE THE REAL-TIME WIDTH
                    sliderMin: Float(100),
                    sliderMax: Float(20000),
                    step: 100
                )
            }
        )
```

And the function that computes the new value:

```
private func calculateNewValue(x: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, sliderMin: Float, sliderMax: Float, step: Float) -> Double {
    
    // What percent filled are we at the X position?
    var percentFillAtX = x / width
    
    // Clamp between [0, 1]
    percentFillAtX = max(percentFillAtX, 0)
    percentFillAtX = min(percentFillAtX, 1)
    
    // Calculate the final value and clamp to the step
    let value = ((sliderMax - sliderMin) * Float(percentFillAtX)) + sliderMin
    let stepRemainder = value.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: step)
    
    return Double(value - stepRemainder)
}
```

Maybe iOS17 will fix all of this so we don't have to create these workarounds.